# float right in angular autocomplete not working in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm using angular autocomplete and I intend to display two texts for each line: one on the left and the other on the far right. I'm using float: right to achieve that. It works fine except on firefox.

```
<md-item-template>
<span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">    {{item.display}}</span>
<span style="float: right;">this should be on the far right</span>
</md-item-template>
```

Moving the float span above the other span fixes it, but then when the window size gets smaller, the spans overlap on each other.. I would want to floated span to appear as long as there is enough space to contain it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of angular-material's [child alignment](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment) instead of using float.

Try something like this (not tested):

```
<md-item-template>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
        <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">
            {{item.display}}
        </span>
        <span>this should be on the far right</span>
    </div>
</md-item-template>
```